# Regex - Get whole text from string to double line break

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text:

"Car1
This is Car1

Car2
This is Car2

"

I want to search via a variable "Car" To find fx Car1 and then I want all the following text till I hit the double line break (just before Car2).

How do I get this with regex? regex is killing me ! :)

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below takes in a variable `v`, escapes it (so that our variable's content doesn't break our regex - see [Regular Expression - Escaping from Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping)), then we append `.*?(?=[\r\n]{2})` and use the flags `g` and `s` (further explained below).

```js
s = 'Car1 This is Car1\n\nCar2 This is Car2\n\n'
v = 'Car'
x = new RegExp(v.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&') + '.*?(?=[\r\n]{2})', 'gs')
console.log(s.match(x))
```

Explanation of `.*?(?=(?:\r\n?|\n){2})`:

- `.*?` match any character any number of times, but as few as possible (matches newline characters because of the `s` flag)
- `(?=(?:[\r\n]{2})` positive lookahead ensuring two newline characters follow

Comment: I want to my variable is v = "Car1" I want the associated text = "This is Car1". Can you help ?

Comment: @TheAsker not sure I fully understand; Your input is `Car`, what's your expected output for both lines?